# How to delete a subdocument on mongodb and pymogo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

Hey guys i'm having some troubles with some arrays in MongoDB.

I'm trying to delete the subdocument with the {name:"projeto1"}, from the Collection Agents.

There is a way to access that and delete?

```py
from pprint import pprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import ReturnDocument
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import json
import jsonpickle
from bson import json_util

class GetAgents:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
        self.db = self.client['mindnet'] #nome do banco
        self.collection_agents = self.db['AGENTS'] #nome da coleção


    def create_backup(self):
        self.collection_backup = self.db['BACKUP'] #nome da coleção
        all_agents = self.collection_agents.find({})
        a = list(all_agents)
        self.collection_backup.insert_many(a)

    def remove_session(self, _agente, _projeto):




agent = GetAgents()
try:
    agent.create_backup()
    agent.remove_session('agente1','projeto2')
except:
    agent.remove_session('agente1', 'projeto2')
```

[this is how the DB is working now, i want to delete by the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0KHP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [pop](http://%7B'name':%20'a',%20'sessions':%20[%7B'model':%200%7D,%20%7B'model':%201%7D,%20%7B'model':%202%7D]%7D%20%7B'name':%20'a',%20'sessions':%20[%7B'model':%200%7D,%20%7B'model':%202%7D]%7D) command to remove a list element.

Try this example

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.doc.insert_one({'name': 'a',
                   'sessions': [{'model': 0},
                                {'model': 1},
                                {'model': 2}]})

doc = db.doc.find_one({'name': 'a'}, {'_id': 0})
print(doc)
doc['sessions'].pop(1)
db.doc.replace_one({'name': 'a'}, doc, upsert=True)
doc = db.doc.find_one({'name': 'a'}, {'_id': 0})
print(doc)
```

gives:

```
{'name': 'a', 'sessions': [{'model': 0}, {'model': 1}, {'model': 2}]}
{'name': 'a', 'sessions': [{'model': 0}, {'model': 2}]}
```